# Minimum number of rows and columns to insert to make a 2D matrix mirrored in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 2D matrix in Python, and I want to calculate the minimum number of rows and columns that need to be added to make it a mirrored matrix without changing the original matrix. We can add a new row or column to the end or even in the middle of the existing matrix.

Here is my current Python code:

```
def get_min_rows_columns_to_mirror(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    columns = len(matrix[0]) if rows > 0 else 0

    # Calculate the minimum number of rows and columns to be added
    min_rows = max(0, (rows % 2) - 1)
    min_columns = max(0, (columns % 2) - 1)

    return mi
```

Is there a more efficient or concise way to achieve this? I'm open to suggestions and improvements.

Edit: a vertically mirrored matrix would look as follows. Click [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjNBi.png)

Comment: Define “mirrored matrix”. What if it is already “mirrored” (whatever that is).